# Why does this print the wrong number in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numbers

In my python script, I do the following:

```
>>> x = 0123456
```

However, when I print this, it comes out as this:

```
>>> x = 0123456
>>> print x
42798
```

Does this have to do with the zero in front? Or is it just my computer?

Comment: Numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as octal.

Comment: Some of the sub-questions can be trivially self-answered: 1) To see if "it has to do with zero in front:" `x = 123456`; 2) To "verify it's not your computer" (http://ideone.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number literal starts with 0 is considered as an octal number. You can realize it like this

```
print int("123456", 8)   # 42798
```

Here we asked `int` function to consider the number `123456` as a base 8 number.

**Note** that this will work only in Python 2.7. Because in Python 2.7, [octal numbers are defined like this](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals)

```
octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+ | "0" octdigit+
```

But [in Python 3.x, this is changed to](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals)

```
octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+
```

So, In Python 3.x this will be treated as Syntax error,

```
x = 0123456
# SyntaxError: invalid token
```

If at all you are going to represent octal numbers in your code, you should do

```
x = 0o123456    # Remember the o (for octal) after the first 0
```

This will work in both Python 2.7 and 3.x

Comment: Thanks! Sorry about the duplicate, I searched but I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 1):

leading `0` means it's being interpreted as an octal number. Octal 0123456 is 42798 decimal. Similarly, if you had `x = 0x123456`, you'd be printing out 1193046, because `0x` means it's a hexadecimal number.